# Topological Definition of Continuity

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I am having some trouble understanding the mechanics of the topological definition of continuity.

It has been defined as follows:

A function $ f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ is continuous if for every open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R^m}$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(V) = \{x \in \mathbb{R^n} | f(x) \in V \subset \mathbb{R^m}\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Why, specifically, under the context of topology do we define continuty in terms of the inverse? Is there an equivalent definition of this that goes "the other way around"?

Furthermore, this is not an iff implication. That is, an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ does not imply $V \subseteq \mathbb{R^m}$ is closed. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Are you comfortable with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition for continuity?

Comment: If you understand the closure, it is equivalent to say $f(\overline A) \subset \overline{f(A)}$ for any subset $A$.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the $ϵ−δ$ definition of continuity.

Comment: @JustinYoung Is A the subset of X (the "input space")? Your statement does make sense though. But what if I am not talking about the closure?

Comment: @MH1993 In the last part of the question, are you asking whether $V \subseteq \mathbb R^m$ is **open** if and only if $f^{-1}(V) \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is open?

Comment: Possibly useful are these two old sci.math posts of mine: [Characterizations of continuity](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5144243) (18 September 2006) and [Characterizations of continuity](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5422934) (9 December 2006)

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was implied since I plugged it into $f$, but yes, $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topological notion of continuity (which is stated for *any* topological space - even not metric, not only the $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a generalisation of the intuitions you may have from the real analysis (with $\delta$s and $\epsilon$s). Think of a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  If it is *not* continuous at some point you may choose the neighbourhood violating the definition.

Let's analyse a simple example: $\operatorname{signum} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  - equal 1 for positive numbers and 0 otherwise. If we take an open set $X = (-1/2, 1/2)$, its counter image $\operatorname{signum}^{-1}(X) = (-\infty, 0]$ is not open (because the function is "broken" in 0).

The definition is "iff" in the sense that functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are continuous in the $\delta - \epsilon$ sense iff they have this property. However, there are more interesting topologies than the one on $\mathbb{R}$, where the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition does not make sense, but this one allows us to define what does it mean for the function to be continuous.

I think drawing it could help you to get more intuitions if this is not enough ; )

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Yeah, I think I need to draw out a few examples.

Comment: Actually, just to add on, how did you come up with the open set X = (-1/2, 1/2)? And why is the inverse of this (-oo, 0]?

Comment: Well, to unfold the definition of an inverse image of $X$: it is just a set of all points, which are mapped to $X$, so in this case - in fact just points, which are mapped to 0 (as the function value is either equal to 1 0r 0). So which points are mapped to 0 by $signum$? All non-positive, which means: $(-oo, 0]$ ;)

Comment: I am a bit confused because you've defined X as being a subset of the domain, so the function is mapped to (-oo,0] makes sense, but I don't see why we used the inverse here. (Even if it is by definition). Wouldn't it be the case that $signum^{-1}((-oo,0]) = (-1/2, 1/2)$ instead? And not the way you've defined it? Or am I wrong? :o I might be getting confused. Time for a quick coffee break.

Comment: Though just to be more precise, we are saying X $\subseteq\ \mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: $signum ((-oo, 0]) = \{0\} \subseteq (-1/2, 1/2)$, so for sure $(-oo, 0] \subseteq signum^{-1} ((-1/2, 1/2)) $. In fact, tey are just $equal$, as other points are mapped to $1 \notin (-1/2, 1/2)$. The example uses just $\mathbb{R}$ to make it more simple.

Comment: And what we actually do here is not random: we have chosen a point $x$ where function f is not continuous and some open neighbourhood $X$ (a "padding") of x s.t. the the value $f(x) \in X$, but the value "close to" $x$ where the function jumps is not in $X$. If you think a moment you'll see that it can be done iff the function is "broken" (that is: not continuous). And the $f^{-1}(X)$ will not be open.

Answer (score 3):

Continuous functions have many important properties. One crucial one in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that they preserve convergent sequences. In other words, if I have a sequence $x_{n}$ converging to $x$, then $f(x_{n})$ converges to $f(x)$. What does it mean for $f(x_{n})$ to converge to $f(x)$? From the topological perspective, it means that the sequence $f(x_{n})$ eventually enters (and stays in) every open set $V$ containing $f(x_{n})$. If $f^{-1}(V)$ is open, then since it contains $x$ the sequence $x_{n}$ must eventually enter and remain in it, since we have assumed $x_{n} \to x$. From this we can conclude that $f(x_{n})$ eventually enter and remain in $V$.

The key point of this proof is that we are using information in the domain to prove stuff in the range/codomain, so we need to be able to "pull back" objects from the former to the latter. If $f^{-1}(V)$ is open for every open $V$, then all the open sets in the codomain ``come from" open sets in the domain. But if we insist instead that $f(V)$ is open for $V$ open, then the codomain may have many extra open sets that are not of the form $f(V)$, and we would be at a loss to prove anything about them.

Answer (score 1):

There are several equivalent def'ns of continuity. Some of them are more suitable for certain problems than others.

1.The inverse of an open set of the range is open in the domain.

2.The inverse of a closed set of the range is closed in the domain.

3. For a given $p$ in the domain of $f:$ Suppose that whenever $f(p)\in V$ with $V$  open in the range, there is an open $U$ in the domain, with $p\in U,$ such that $\forall x'\in U\;(f(x')\in V).$ Then we say that  $f$ is continuous  at $p.$ And $f$ is continuous iff $f$ is continuous at every point $p$ of its domain. This is the topological generalization of the "$\delta, \epsilon$" criterion for continuity of a real function.
4. For a function $f:X\to Y$ : Whenever $S\subset X$ and $p\in Cl_X(S)$ then $$f(p)\in Cl_Y\{f(p'):p'\in S\}.$$ This is the topological generalization of a criterion for continuity of $f$ when $(X,d), (Y,e)$ are metric spaces: Whenever $(p_n)_n$ is a sequence in $X$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(p,p_n)=0$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}e(f(p),f(p_n))=0.$
5. Local continuity: $f$ is continuous iff every $p$ in the domain of $f$ belongs to an open set $U_p$ in the domain such that the restriction of $f$ to the domain $U_p$ is continuous. This is useful in some constructions. E,g. where we have $X=\cup_{n\in N}U_n$ where each $U_n$ is open in $X, $ and $U_n\subset U_{n+1},$ and we have continuous $f_n:U_n\to Y$ with $f_{n+1}|U_n=f_n.$ Then $\cup_{n\in N}f_n$ is continuous.

Comment: 1.The inverse of an open set of the range is open in the domain.

2.The inverse of a closed set of the range is closed in the domain.

How do these imply continuity?

Comment: Nevermind. Got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $X, Y$ be two topological spaces.  A function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be *continuous at a point $x_{0} \in X$* if into every neighborhood of $y_{0} = f(x_{0}) \in Y$ this function maps some neighborhood of $x_{0}$.

(See also the definitions of continuity and equivalent conditions in: (a) Komogorov and Fomin's book on real analysis, (b) Vulikh's *Brief Course of Functions of a Real Variable*.)