# Motivation behind the definition of measurable functions.

Tags: measure-theory, intuition, measurable-functions, motivation

In measure theory,we work with *non-pathological* sets and functions called *measurable* sets and functions.The definition of measurable function $f:(X,\mathcal S)\to \mathbb R$ is defined as a function such that $f^{-1}(B)$ is $\mathcal S$-measurable for any $B\in \mathcal B_\mathbb R$,the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.More generally a measurable function between two measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal S)$ and $(Y,\mathcal F)$ is defined to be a function $f:X\to Y$ such that $E\subset Y$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable $\implies$ $f^{-1}(E)$ is $\mathcal S$-measurable.My question is why these functions are well behaved and non-pathological.How did mathematicians come up with such a strange criterion?What is the motivation behind the definition of *measurable* functions?Are they *nice* in the sense that they can be approximated by a sequence of simple functions?

Comment: How do you define pathology resp. well-behaved ? For the intuition see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387465/intuitive-understanding-of-measurability-in-probability-theory/4387484#4387484).

Comment: @KurtG. These are probability approaches.I am looking for a naive explanation that even a student who does not know probability and all,will understand.

Comment: @KurtG. Pathology is loosely defined.For example,*Banach-Tarski paradox* is a pathological example.Also non-measurable sets are pathological in the sense that disjoint sets do not add up in measure.

Comment: The post I already linked is what I would show a student. The rest of the question is very vague and imho unanswerable. In (forgive me) probability theory we typically ask for the probability of events such as $\{f\in E\}$ which requires $f$ to be measurable.

Comment: @KurtG. Can I say that measurable functions are nice in the sense that they can be approximated by an increasing sequence of simple functions?

Comment: As I wrote in the linked post. To be precise: "A general measurable function $f$ can be decomposed into its positive and negative parts $f^+$ and $f^−$. Each such part can be approximated by an increasing sequence of "piecewise" constant (also called simple) functions."

Comment: When first introduced to measurable functions, I think about it as the condition we need to integrate a positive function, as discussed in questions like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1081021/26369

Comment: "How did mathematicians come up with such a strange criterion?" It took a couple of centuries (between Newton/Leibniz and Lebesgue) to build this theory properly, with many false claims and counter-examples in the middle. Some intuition can be given, but also in a way this is technical because it needs to be for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We very often care about maps that preserve the structure of the spaces. For example, for topological spaces, a continuous map is one which preserves the openness of a set (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977317/topological-definition-of-continuity) for intuition and for why we care). This is analogous to measurable maps (in fact, measurable maps are continuous). They preserve the measurability of a set. The standard example for a non-measurable function is the indicator of a set $A \subset X$, where $A \not \in \mathcal{S}$ (i.e. $A$ is not a measurable set). Then, the pre-image of $\{1\}$ is $A$, which is by definition not in $\mathcal{S}$. Now, such sets $A$ are hard to construct and are rather unintuitive, but the point is that measurable functions allow you to use the "information" in the domain to conclude something about the range. In this case, information about the measurable set $\{1\}$ cannot be traced back to any information in the domain, and we wouldn't be able to do much with it (such as integrating).

The fact that non-negative measurable maps can be approximated by an increasing sequence of simple functions is a *consequence* of measurability. Note that simple functions are *defined* to be nice. So although it is true that measurable functions can be approximated by a sequence of simple functions, in my opinion it doesn't tell you much about measurability.

In summary, measurable maps are maps that preserve the structure of measurable spaces. I hope this helps.